# C# - XML Child Nodes to Text Box

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am having trouble putting a child node text into a rich text box in c#. Here is what I have tried so far:

Here is the XML File:

```
<DATA_LIST>
  <Customer>
    <Full_Name>TEST</Full_Name>
    <Total_Price>100</Total_Price>
    <Discounts>20</Discounts>
  </Customer>
</DATA_LIST>
```

Code

```
//Loads XML Document
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(path + "\\Origami - User\\info.xml");

//My attempt at selecting a child node and making it a string
XmlNode xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("DATA_LIST\\Customer");
string TotalPriceString = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Total_Price").InnerText;
txtLogBox.AppendText("test: " + TotalPriceString);
```

This is the error I get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathException'
>   occurred in System.Xml.dll
>
> Additional information: 'DATA_LIST\Customer' has an invalid token.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath for selecting Customer node is wrong, it should be `/DATA_LIST/Customer`

See [XPath Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) for more details and examples.

Comment: What a stupid mistake. Bit of tweaking and it is working now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't use backslash in XPath. Use slash instead:

```
XmlNode xNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("DATA_LIST/Customer");
string TotalPriceString = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Total_Price").InnerText;
```

You can use single XPath to get price:

```
 string totalPrice =  
    doc.SelectSingleNode("DATA_LIST/Customer/Total_Price").InnerText;
```

Another suggestion is usage of LINQ to XML. You can get price as number

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
int totalPrice = (int)xdoc.XPathSelectElement("DATA_LIST/Customer/Total_Price");
```

Or without XPath:

```
int totalPrice = (int)xdoc.Root.Element("Customer").Element("Total_Price");
```